# how does android gesture builder work?

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition

What is the technology behind android's GestureBuilder tool, that allows you to draw a varieties of gestures and later able to recognize user gestures as one of the gestures you've drawn? Some links and pointers would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: You know you have the source code for Gesture Builder already, don't you? Take a look at it.

Comment: That's good to know. However I was hoping for an article to explain it. I am not a programmer at all. Have you read it or have any lead? It'll be greatly appreciated.